# How to deal with "how do I interpret this?" type questions

Tags: discussion

It seems like exceedingly I come across a large number of posts that ask questions that share some resemblance to the question "these are my results, how do I interpret them?" It seems like many of these questions end up in the close vote queue.

What is the official procedure for dealing with these types of questions, are they automatically considered "off topic" or considered appropriate when sufficient details/clarity is provided?

Interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: good question. might be helpful to link some examples

Comment: @oW great point, will do some digging

Answer (score 3):

I have voted to close some of those questions in the past days, which may explain the spike you saw in the queue. I specifically targeted questions where 1) some clarification were asked in the comments, 2) those clarification weren't provided and 3) the author hasn't came back in a long time. After checking that there is effectively not enough info in the original question, I proposed to close them as they still "needs details or clarity".

I don't think all those questions need to be closed as "off topic". On the contrary I have found very insteresting ones. (But I upvoted those instead of voting to close - that might be why you didn't see the interesting ones). A general rule would be detrimental to those good questions. I propose we stick to closing the ones that can't be answered without details that weren't provided.

Regarding those questions we are left with : ensuring that enough detail is provided initially (which is rather difficult without changing SE interface and rules) and make sure those questions and their answers are reachable (which is possible trough editing the title).